# APScheduler with different timezone

Tags: python, timezone, apscheduler

I am using APScheduler in my program to schedule the job on specific datetime. However I am dealing with datetime with different timezone than the localtime. So my datetime that I pass in to  APScheduler always a timezone aware datime...

```
sched.add_date_job(my_job, exec_date, ['text'])
```

I always got:  can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
from APScheduler...

Please help...

Answer (score 4):

Using the new version of the APScheduler (3.4.0) you can set up the timezone as bellow:

#### Instance the APScheduler in *UTC* Timezone

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler({'apscheduler.timezone': 'UTC'})
```

#### Instance the APScheduler in *Europe/London* Timezone

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler({'apscheduler.timezone': 'Europe/London'})
```

Source: http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#configuring-the-scheduler

Answer (score 2):

APScheduler 2.x does not support timezones. This has, however, been fixed in APScheduler 3.0. The bad news is that 3.0 has not yet been released, and the API has not yet been finalized either. The good news is that the hard part is done and I've promised to deliver 3.0 in Q2/2014.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alex for the information, I am anticipated to use APScheduler 3.0 soon.  In the mean time I had try patch the 2.x version to support timezone by changing any occurrences of datetime.now() in scheduler.py  to datetime.now(timezone("utc")) and I always schedule the job with timezone aware datetime..It seems to work for me..